# Solr ate all Memory and throws -bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device on Server

Tags: bash, memory, solr, server, ram

I have been started **solr** for **long time approx 2 weeks** then I saw that Solr ate around **22 GB** from **28 GB RAM** of my **Server**.

While checking **status** of **Solr**, using `bin/solr -i` it throws `-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`

I stopped the **Solr**, and restarted the **solr**. It is working fine.

What's the **problem** actually. Didn't get?

And what is the **solution** for that?

I **never** want that Solr gets stop/halt while running.

Answer (score 3):

First you should check the space on your file system. For example using `df -h`. Post the output here.

Is there any mount-point without free space?

2nd: find out the reason, why there is no space left. Your question handles two different thing: no space left on file system an a big usage of RAM.

Solr stores two different kind of data: the search index an the data himself.
Storing the data is only needed, if you like to output the documents after finding them in index. For example if you like to use highlighting. So take a look at your `schema.xml` an decide for every singe field, if it must be stored or if "indexing" the field is enough for your needs. Use the `stored=true` parameter for that.

Next: if you rebuild the index: keep in mind, that you need double space on disc during index rebuild.

You also could think about to move your index/data files to an other disk.

If you have solved you "free space" problem on disc, so you probably don't have an RAM issue any more.

If there is still a RAM problem, please post you java start parameter. There you can define, how much RAM is available for Solr. Solr needs a lot of virtual RAM, but an moderate size of physical RAM.

And: you could post the output of your logfile.

Comment: commanding df -h: `/dev/sda1        29G   29G     0 100% /` => /dev/sda1 has 0 (Avail).

Comment: So you should check, why the disc space is empty. Find out big files. That could be log-files or index files from your solr. Use `du -sh *` to find the directory with bigest storage needs.

Comment: Size of solr logs files are 2942MB and indexed data is 2GB and transaction Log size is 448KB. Is solr logs file harming the performance or there is any other reason.

Comment: you should take a look into the newest solr logs, to find out, whats going on. And you should remove old logs. You also can rest an current logfile, that is opened by solr, if you us that > myBigLogfilelog` like this:  `user@host:>   > myBigLogfilelog`

Comment: Extremely sorry. Didn't get you. and how to check current log file?

Comment: by reading the content: to read the last lines: `tail myBigLogFile.log`  to display the whole file use `cat myBigLogFile.log` or `less myBigLogFile.log`  (use key `q`  for exit and key `G` for last line)

Comment: @ The Bndr: Okay.  logs are visible. what to check inside that.

Comment: @iNikkz Is this the first time, you examine problems on an IT system? Lock for errors or strange things inside the logfile.... Probably the system tells you, what the problem is.